# How to resolve error about patching, hunk failed

Tags: openwrt, patch

I try to add a patch about last kernel and don't know why is not working.. idea?
thanks

```
openwrtt$ patch -p1 < kernel.patch
patching file include/kernel-version.mk
Hunk #1 FAILED at 7.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file include/kernel-version.mk.rej
patching file target/linux/bcm27xx/patches-5.10/950-0139-xhci-implement-xhci_fixup_endpoint-for-interval-adju.patch
patching file target/linux/bcm27xx/patches-5.10/950-0151-hid-usb-Add-device-quirks-for-Freeway-Airmouse-T3-an.patch
patching file target/linux/bcm27xx/patches-5.10/950-0249-kbuild-Disable-gcc-plugins.patch
patching file target/linux/bcm27xx/patches-5.10/950-0323-media-i2c-Add-driver-for-Sony-IMX477-sensor.patch
patching file target/linux/bcm27xx/patches-5.10/950-0657-Documentation-devicetree-Add-documentation-for-imx37.patch
patching file target/linux/bcm27xx/patches-5.10/950-0733-usb-xhci-workaround-for-bogus-SET_DEQ_PENDING-endpoi.patch
Hunk #1 FAILED at 26.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file target/linux/bcm27xx/patches-5.10/950-0733-usb-xhci-workaround-for-bogus-SET_DEQ_PENDING-endpoi.patch.rej
patching file target/linux/generic/backport-5.10/610-v5.13-57-netfilter-flowtable-Set-offload-timeouts-according-t.patch
patching file target/linux/generic/backport-5.10/732-net-next-1-of-net-pass-the-dst-buffer-to-of_get_mac_address.patch
patching file target/linux/generic/pending-5.10/834-ledtrig-libata.patch
patching file target/linux/oxnas/patches-5.10/999-libata-hacks.patch
patching file target/linux/realtek/patches-5.10/008-5.17-watchdog-add-realtek-otto-watchdog-timer.patch
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `patch` command tells you which files were successfully patched, and which were not. For example,

> ```
> patch -p1 < kernel.patch
> patching file include/kernel-version.mk
> Hunk #1 FAILED at 7.
> 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file include/kernel-version.mk.rej
> ```

You need to look at the rejects file, in this case `include/kernel-version.mk.rej` and try to identify why the patch couldn't be applied to the file `include/kernel-version.mk`. It might be something simple such as different spacing since you didn't use the `-l` (`--ignore-whitespace`) flag. Once you have identified the issue you need to apply the patch, probably by hand.

Then repeat the process for the other failed patch.